# Add Image to Assets Folder UWP C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, uwp, assets

Why can't I add images to my UWP assets folder? I usually use C#, but I have to use  C++ because I'll eventually be turning this into an optional package (somebody tell me if I'm wrong, and I can write optional packages in C#).

Using Visual Studio, I right click on the Assets folder in the Solutions Explorer click Add->Existing Item and then click on my image.  It shows up in Visual Studio, but it doesn't actually get added to the Assets folder so I'm unable to view it when I load my app.  I wouldn't think that it matters whether I use C++ or C#, but one is working and not the other.

I've tried rebuilding the project, rebooting the computer, repairing Visual Studio and I'm still stuck.

As suggested by [paxbun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6943262/paxbun), I tried using File Explorer to add the file.  If I added the file in the Assets folder with the project files, it didn't help.  I was able to get the code to work by adding the file to the AppX folder in the Debug folder, but this won't help when I'm ready to release (to make sure, I did a quick sideload).

I haven't put much at all in the code, but you can view it at https://github.com/benjasperson/SimpleCPPImage

Comment: Contrary to C# projects, Visual Studio does not add assets and folders automatically for C++ projects. You have to create folders and copy files manually.

Comment: @paxbun I don't think I understand.  When I open a blank C++ UWP project, it does create an assets folder with the default assets (the squares with xs).  When I try to add to the folder by right clicking on it in the solutions manager, it shows up in Visual Studio, but not when I actually view the folder.  How do you add assets and folders in c++?  I don't see anything in my code that adds the default assets or the assets folder, but they work just fine.

Comment: I mean, you should copy assets with File Explorer, not programmatically.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copying assets into UWP application package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32144287/copying-assets-into-uwp-application-package)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upon further research, I found my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32144287/copying-assets-into-uwp-application-package).

Clicking "Show all files" in the Solution Explorer and then setting "Include in project" to true was all I needed to do.