# How to change build settings for assets on per directory level for UWP-apps in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

I'm working on some UWP-app using Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition and added a directory with lots of files as assets. Those files need to be deployed with the application while preserving their directory structure and are no language or screen related resources, but YAML files for some different purpose.

What I did was simply dragging and dropping my folder if interest into the VS-GUI onto the `Assets` folder, which made the folder available in the project. The problem is that afterwards one needs to set the build options for all those added files. While one can [mark all files and set their build options at once](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32145766/2055163), this still is tedious with lots of files in lots of directories.

Making things worse, my added assets change from time to time, folders and files get removed entirely, renamed, new ones added etc. I don't want to manually keep track of those changes, so the only solution I currently have would be to remove my assets from the project, add them again and once again mark all files in all folders and set their build options.

So, instead of marking individual files, can build options be set per-directory for all files underneath?

Any other ideas on how to better handle my use case?

Comment: `MakeAppx.exe` might be wort a look in the long term: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/win32/appxpkg/make-appx-package--makeappx-exe-#to-create-a-package-using-a-mapping-file

Comment: From your reply, it seems that you have found a solution. Can it solve your issue?

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT No, it's only a note, I would prefer something available in the GUI and properly added in the project files etc. anyway. That doesn't seem to be the case with `MakeAppx.exe`.

Comment: Currently there is no other way. It seems remove assets from the project, add them again and once again mark all files in all folders and set their build options is the best way. I suggest that it's better to ensure the stability of your folder, and not to change the content inside frequently. This will solve your problem fundamentally.

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT In my use case the `YAML` files implement policies for business logic and are designed to change frequently to support additional use cases of customers. So not changing/refactoring is not an option.

Comment: It seems you can only remove assets from the project, add them again and once again mark all files in all folders and set their build options manually.